# IE 11 issue - Java applet comes always on top of all HTML elements

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, applet

I am working in an HTML application which has applets. The problem is applet is coming on top of all HTML elements. I have a dialog modal (html div) that has to be displayed in a page, but if the page has applet in it, the applet is coming on top of the modal which is not good. Please help me out here.

Applet plugin:

```
<plug:plugin
        type="applet"
        code="ScrollableChart1"
        align="top"
        width="100%"
        height="380"
        name="ChartApplet"
        id="ChartApplet"
        classloaderpolicy="none">
        <plug:params>

            <plug:param name="appletKey" value="5376-267"/>
            <plug:param name="java_codebase" value="<%= Context.getAppletsPath( request ) %>"/>
            <plug:param name="archive" value="test3.jar,test2.jar,test1.jar,test.jar"/>
            <plug:param name="properties" value="style/rsrc_analysis_bar_chart.properties" />
            <plug:param name="pColorPalette" value="<%=databean.getColorPalette()%>" />
            <plug:param name="legendTitleBarString" value='<%=psession.getStringLocalizer().getLocalString("ttl.legend")%>' />
            <plug:param name="legendTitle" value="<%=databean.getLegendTitle()%>" />
            <plug:param name="dataURL" value="<%=url%>" />
            <plug:param name="hasThresholds" value="<%=Boolean.toString(databean.hasThresholds())%>" />
            <plug:param name="yAxisTitle" value="<%=databean.getYAxisTitle()%>" />
            <plug:param name="3D" value="true" />
            <plug:param name="stackedBar" value="<%=Boolean.toString(chartTypeObj.equals(ChartType.STACKED_HISTOGRAM))%>" />
            <plug:param name="maxDataSet" value='<%=databean.getMaxDataSet() %>' />
            <plug:param name="scrollbar" value="true" />
            <plug:param name="dwellYString" value="<%=databean.getYValueFormat()%>" />
            <plug:param name="dwellYLabelPrecision" value="<%=String.valueOf(databean.getYValuePrecision())%>" />
            <plug:param name="plotAreaTop" value="0.83" />
            <plug:param name="plotAreaBottom" value="0.17" />
            <plug:param name="titleString" value='<%=databean.getChartTitle() %>' />
            <plug:param name="titleFont" value="SansSerif,14,1"/>
            <plug:param name="titleColor" value="015F91"/>
            <plug:param name="subTitleFont" value="SansSerif,12,1"/>
            <plug:param name="subTitleColor" value="015F91"/>
            <plug:param name="subTitleString" value='<%=databean.getChartSubTitle() %>' />
        </plug:params>
    </plug:plugin>
```

HTML modal:

```
<div class="modal modal hide fade custom-modal assignment-role-tab-modal in" id="dashboard-dialog" role="dialog" style="display: block;z-index:1050;">
```

No matter what value I give to z-index, the applet comes on top always. This is working fine in firefox and chrome, but failing only in IE.

IE version : 11.0.9600.18537CO

Comment: Um...Chrome stopped supporting Java applets months (Windows) if not years (Linux) ago. Firefox was supposed to at the end of last year. I'm puzzled how they could be "working fine"?!

Comment: I think this is an issue with IE. I've also experienced this not only with applets but with websites too. Rest assured if your stuff works in other browsers. BTW, you should forsake applets for good; they're already dead. Move to some other newer technology.

Comment: I hope that I could do that, but part of my requirement is to replace some of the applets in my application with html. For that purpose, the browsers are configured to run applets.

Comment: I tried giving this param in the plugin, but did not work. <plug:param name="wmode" value="opaque" />